# django queryset and templates

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am quite new to django, and I have built a small page using forms.
When I go to the template and use the template tags, such as:

```
{{form.q}}
```

everthing is fine, and I see the form input field. However, I do not really like the input "box" it provides and I want to override this feature.

So, in my HTML, I would have something like:

```
<input id="customfield" name="q" type="text"/>
```

I tried the above, and everything seems to work fine. However, if I use for example:

```
<input id="customfield" name="{{form.q}}" type="text"/>
```

it dosent work. So, my question is:

[1] Is it ok to use name="q" or how can one specify {{form.q}} if I have a custom input?
   [2] Are there any disadvantages (like sql injection) when using name="q" as opposed to simply using {{form.q}}?

Sorry for the 101 questions!

Comment: What is form, and what type of field is q?

Comment: It (q) is an input search field.

Comment: What are you trying to customize about it ?

Comment: Iam trying to customise the look of the search box. So, I have a CSS element for the same and Id like to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly how you would build a form if you wanted this much control in the template.

You'd take this course when other django shortcuts have failed, like one of the build in [`widgets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) that determine the way your field is rendered.

Update: after reading your comment, if you just want to inject attributes to the `input` element, you can pass the widget a dictionary containing `attribute:value` pairs.

```
q = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'foobar'}))
```

SQL injection is irrelevant here (you'd worry about this when a user has something to do with SQL written on your server) and there are no disadvantages, aside from the code being more difficult to write and maintain.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment Yuji. Did you mean that it is OK and safe to go about doing: <input id="customfield" name="q" type="text"/>
?

Comment: @JamesW, of course! What do you think {{ form.q }} ultimately renders as? :) There is no difference to a browser whether django generates it automatically, or you write it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks Yuji again. I actually did prefer using name="q" as it gives me more control to include js and other non-django widgets.